# Java Field not showing with initial retrieved value (SMART GWT 6.1)

Tags: java, smartgwt

```
if (device != null) {
            logger.info("device " + device.getValue().toString());
            if (device.getValue() != null && device.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                logger.info("device inside is" + device.getValue().toString());
                name_of_device.show();
                
                dynamicForm.redraw();
            } else {
                logger.info("Initial is hiding");
                name_of_device.hide();
                
                dynamicForm.redraw();
            }
        }

        if (device != null) {
            device.addChangedHandler(new ChangedHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ChangedEvent changedEvent) {

                    if(device.getValue().toString().equals("Yes") || device.getValue().toString().equals("Y"))
                    {

                        name_of_device.show();
                        name_of_device.setRequired(true);

                    }
                    else {
                        name_of_device.hide();
                    
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Hi Everyone, I am facing an issue where the code is working in the changedHandler where if the device.getValue() is Y the name_of_device field will show, but after I have saved the value and access to this method again, even though the value in the field is Y, the name_of_device_field will not be showing, but if I click on the changedHandler again, it is showing the correct behaviour.

Kindly advice what may be the issue and possible solutions. Thank you